# How to split a string into substrings and store into a List - c#

Tags: c#, string, list, substring, substr

I need to split a string into multiple substrings and store those substrings into a list.

Here is an example of the possible contents stored in my initial string:

```
  "{"Stocks": [{"APPLE-775121": false, "AMZN-007612": true, "GOLD-847571": true}]}"
```

The initial string is ever changing, their could be multiple stocks names in there. I need to extract these items only and store into a list of strings:

```
    APPLE-775121
    AMZN-007612
    GOLD-847571
```

Having a little trouble parsing the string, I'm new to C# and don't know about all the useful string functions that exist.

So far what I have done is parsed the InitialString to a new string (named ParsedString) which contains:

```
  "APPLE-775121": false, "AMZN-007612": true, "GOLD-847571": true
```

Can I get some help parsing the rest of this string and storing the substrings into a list?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You will first want to create a class to house that Stock data.  From there, you can use [Newtonsoft's Json conversion utilities](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) to extract your list.  I forget which, but some project templates actually come with the Newtonsoft package already installed, but if it's not there by default, you can get it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
void Main()
{
    var str = "{\"Stocks\": [{\"APPLE-775121\": false, \"AMZN-007612\": true, \"GOLD-847571\": true}]}";
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockContainer>(str);
    var stockList = obj.Stocks.SelectMany(dictEntry => dictEntry.Keys).ToList();
    Console.Write(stockList);  //this is what you want
}

public class StockContainer
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, bool>> Stocks {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The issue is I'm getting the initial string from a database, so I don't have control over initializing the string. I can't add those backslashes you added. Will it still work without adding those?

Comment: @anasteele It will work, backlashes are here only to escape special characters :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn is correct.  Assuming this is coming from a database, the .NET CLR will take care of it all for you.  I added them in since I'm "hard-coding" the string for demonstration's sake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, that list always be wrapped in `[` and `]`, and items' names won't contain any `[`, `]`, `{`, `}` and `,` you can use simple `string.Split`:

```
var str = "{\"Stocks\": [{\"APPLE-775121\": false, \"AMZN-007612\": true, \"GOLD-847571\": true}]}";
var listOfItems = str.Split(new char[] { '[', ']', '}', '{' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
var extractedItems = listOfItems.Split(',').Select(item => item.Split(':')[0]).ToArray();
```